# Oracle SQL, How to show results from two tables with the same last letter

Tags: sql

For a homework question it asks me to join two tables when the words end in the same letter. 
Here's my beginning sql statement:

```
select a.*, b.*
   from sec1313_words1 a, sec1313_words2 b
```

sec1313_words1 table looks like this:

```
WORD (column name)
BAT 
IS 
LAUGH
SING (Rows)
```

sec1313_words2 table:

```
WORD (column name)
DOG
HIGH 
IT 
WEEKS (rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `substr` function with a negative second parameter- something like `substr(word, -1, 1)`.

The second parameter is the starting point, and when negative, it counts back from the end.
It's also worth noting that functions such as `substr` can be used in join clauses, i.e. `ON substr(a.WORD, -1, 1) = substr(b.WORD, -1, 1)`.